# REST: Using path parameters, query parameters or JSON for multiple obligatory fields

Tags: rest

I'm creating a route where I have to disable an object and inform the reason of a predetermined list of reasons. It is not an option to have an empty reason (see, `null` reason)

So, I started asking myself which would be the best practice:

- `/{object-id}/{reason-id}/`
- `/{object-id}?reason-id=`
- `{object-id}/` with a JSON body consisting of

```
{
"reason-id": int
}
```

- `/disable/` with a JSON body consisting of

```
{
"object-id": int,
"reason-id": int
}
```

Maybe I am overthinking, but I'd find strange to have an obligatory query parameter or having two path parameters which aren't related to each other in one-to-many or one-to-one fields. If having a reason was optional, then I'd think about using query parameters, but inn this case I just don't know